# how to combine two nodes with different properties merge as one node in cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

how will I combine two nodes with different properties and merge as one node in cypher?

example node 1 has property of name with value of name1 and node 2 has property of classification and value of class1 to be merge as one node,combining the two properties

tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that this is not currently possible dynamically, but if you know what properties you're transferring:

```
MATCH (a:Label), (b:Label)
WHERE <something about a and b>
SET a.constraint = b.constraint, a.other_prop = b.other_prop
DELETE b // If you want do delete b
```

Otherwise I'd suggest using Cypher to load the objects, merge the properties in memory, and then make a query to save the result.  I'd suggest checking out the `SET` clause and the `+=` operator ([here](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-set.html#set-adding-properties-from-maps) which can take a Map (Hash/Dictionary/whatever) and append all of the given properties that way.

Answer (score 1):

i think it will be possible

see http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-set.html

```
MATCH (at { name: 'Andres' }),(pn { name: 'Peter' })
SET at = pn
RETURN at, pn
```

Use += if you don't want to delete the properties of the first node.